# JMXmonitor web application

Tags: monitoring, jmx

I need to monitor memory consumption, class loading, thread details specific to each web application deployed in a tomcat server.  In my use case, there will be a number of WAR files deployed in a single tomcat instance.

I know i can enable JMX to monitor tomcat and can get few details about the applications deployed in it.  But this will not give any information about memory consumption and other details specific to a each web application.

We can enable JMX for a jar file with the below configurations.

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
 YourJavaApp
```

Similar to this, is there any way to enable JMX for a web application.  Again, what I'm looking is to get details like memory consumption, class-loading, thread details separately for each web application.

Thanks,
nks

Answer (score 0):

JMX only provides high level metrics, you may want to use an APM tool to get deeper into your code and provide far better visibility. The three leading products for this are AppDynamics, Dynatrace, and New Relic. I work for AppDynamics if you have questions, I believe we have the best solution on the market today. We also monitor JMX and do much deeper code analysis, and transaction stitching.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Actually, i would like to capture these information in a tool we are developing to monitor application performance.  Also, this monitoring functionality would one among a lot of other modules.  So, i don't see any scope for an external tool.